# Controllers should be 'stateless', does having a final variable for the service object make this stateful?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am following best practices to enhance my codebase for my SpringBoot project and my controller classes conform to all the others but I am unsure if this would constitute statefulness as the service class is not subject to change, would this make it immutable?

Example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {

    final UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
}
```

The userService instance field is set to final and is instantiated in the controller's constructor method, does this mean the controller class breaches this best-practice and is stateful?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `final` keyword just enforces that the concrete `UserService` can't be changed during the life cycle of the `UserController` instance.

Spring `Controllers` are Singletons, so there is one instance per class, which means multiple subsequent requests made to the `Controller` are served by the same instance.

So no, the `final` keyword does not make your Controller stateful. A dependency to another class to do work does not make the calling class (your `Controller`) stateful.

Also: the final keyword just makes the variable reference immutable, i.e., your userService property always points to the same `UserService` instance. However, the `UserService` instance itself may still be mutable (e.g., if it has state, which can be changed). Since `@Service` classes are also Singletons in Spring, you may want to make the `Service` stateless as well.

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies are not contributing to a "state" of the object. For your controllers to do any real work, you have to inject various dependencies (other services). However you should inject this `UserService` with `@Authowired`, just declaring it in a constructor may not work (though I'm not 100% sure).

What would be considered a state is some value that is written when processing request. Anything that is constant is not really a state.

The main goal is to have one controller to handle many requests without any risk of them (requests) interfering with each other.

Comment: Constructor injection does not require `@Autowired` annotation. The code works as is.

Answer (score 0):

No this does not make the controller stateful. I would consider this the best approach. You could make the `UserService` field `private` as well. Constructor injection is preferable to Field injection IMO e.g. https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2019/02/field-setter-constructor-injection.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine. `UserService` is a dependency of your `UserController` and not exactly something that would "add" state to your controller.

Having a stateful controller would look like the following:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {

    final UserService userService;

    private final List<String> requestedUsers = new ArrayList();

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = /{userId})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public User getUser(@PathVariable long userId) {
        requestedUsers.add(userId);
        return this.userService.getUser(userId);
    }
}
```

Now you have a mutable property in your controller class: `requestedUsers`. You change this list every time a GET request is done for a given `userId` by adding this `userId` to the list. This would "add" state to your controller because now it includes mutable data that is shared and changed every time there is a request to the controller. Noteworthy is the fact that even having `requestedUsers` as `final` changes nothing in terms of the statefulness of your controller. The `final` keyword just guarantees that the reference of the `requestedUsers` property does not change, but the actual data structure it points to can be changed (as it is possible with `List`, to which you can add or remove elements without the need to change its reference).